# Blazor: what is the best way to include main page scripts and styles?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

In default Blazor project we get `Pages/_Host.cshtml` file that contains something like a HTML template for the application.

Recently I created my first Razor Component Library (RCL) and it works.
Here's the scripts part for it:

```html
<script src="_content/Woof.Blazor/js/woof.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Woof.Blazor/js/modal.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Woof.Blazor/js/input.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Woof.Blazor/js/datatable.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Woof.Blazor/js/autocomplete.js"></script>
```

The scripts are included manually in my app. Is there a way for the library to add those files to the application template automagically?
BTW, it would be sweet if style sheets could be added automagically too.

EDIT: I just tried to create a `_Scripts.cshtml` file, but it didn't work. Visual Studio shown a lot of weird errors probably caused by missing package, but I don't know. Making the scripts part a partial view? It's not really a part of MVC. So probably I'm wrong.

What I want to achieve is to replace the whole scripts part above with one line, including all predefined and preconfigured scripts from my library.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Of course order of including resources matters, so the support doesn't have to be fully automatic, but it doesn't need to be fully manual too. Let's say JS - if the RCL specify script load order, why not load them in that order? The order could be specified in a way, like a pattern of "scripts before", then ordering of individual files. Totally possible to do.

Comment: I think you should look at CSS/JS isolation: [Publishing a self-contained Blazor component (Razor + CSS + JS) as a NuGet package](https://www.meziantou.net/publishing-a-self-contained-blazor-component-razor-css-js-as-a-nuget-package.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing available out of the box to do what you’re attempting. The reason is that sometimes the order of script and CSS tags really matters.

For example, if I override some classes from Bootstrap but include my CSS files tag before the one for bootstrap then it won’t work. If CSS and JS files were automatically there would be no way to control order leading to this issue.

From you’re question you list several scripts present in your library. I would suggest the approach to take is to bundle and minify those scripts into a single file. Then you would only need to add one reference in any consuming application. This would also speed up the loading of the consuming application as well, it would only need to load a single script, not 5.

There are multiple ways you can achieve this but I think the most common right now is webpack. A quick google will bring up 10s of blog post showing configuration for this, for example, https://ideas.byteridge.com/webpack-minifying-your-production-bundle/. This can all be automated as well into a build pipeline so it can be used with full CI/CD.

Comment: We should to think about how to let our components libraries ready to be included on user solution bundle.

Comment: What do you mean Dani?

Comment: When someone creates and publish a component, usually it says 'add _content/bhlah/blah.js script to _Hosts.cshtnl' (or index.html) It looks weird for users who want to use webpack for their own projects. The same for `.css` files and sass. Is just a comment. Your answer looks great.

Comment: I think I understand. I don't think people have really looked/thought about bundling in Blazor yet. I see lots of apps with multiple unbundled and unminified CSS and JS scripts. To be fair, even my Blazored packages don't ship with minified CSS and JS -- it's on my TODO list  :) I might write up a blog post about it actually...

Comment: Well, this is what I ended with. I use "Bundler & Minifier" extension, it works fine with bundling, however it can't handle minifying my modern JS.

Answer (score 1):

For CSS, you can try my library - BlazorStyled (https://BlazorStyled.io). It dynamically adds styles to a style sheet that you don’t need to include in your template. There are other benefits too such as - you define your styles inside your component and there will never be css clashes so you will never need to use !important again. If you used something like emotion or glamorous in react/cue/angular it’s similar to those.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 5 for css you can use [CSS Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0). it attaches css content to each component, but for js files you need to load the all in _Host.cshtml and you can not load them isolated, you can just call the needed js function later.